# javascript onload hide element based on value of boolean value

Tags: javascript

I am using a boolean value to determine the user's availability. If the boolean value is true, I would like for the timeslot form for that particular day to remain hidden the next time the user returns to the page. I was thinking document onload is the best approach. However, my attempts at creating such a thing have fallen short. What am I missing here? The code in question is the last of the Javascript. Thank you in advance.

```
const sunForm = document.getElementsByClassName('sun_time_slot_form');
const mainForm = document.querySelector('#all-add-form');
const addSunBtn = document.querySelector("#add-sun-form");
const submitFormBtn = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
const totalForms = document.querySelector("[id$='-TOTAL_FORMS']");
const sunDeleteBtn = document.querySelector(".sun_time_slot_form");
let formCount = sunForm.length - 1;

addSunBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newSunForm = sunForm[0].cloneNode(true);
    const formRegex = RegExp(`id_sunday_formset-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');

    formCount++;

    newSunForm.innerHTML = newSunForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `id_sunday_formset-${formCount}-`);
    mainForm.insertBefore(newSunForm, submitFormBtn);
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formCount + 1}`);
});

function updateSunForm() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let sun_form of sunForm) {
        const sunFormRegex = RegExp(`TOTAL_FORMS-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');
        sun_form.innerHTML = sun_form.innerHTML.replace(sunFormRegex, `TOTAL_FORMS-${count++}-`)
    }
}

mainForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-sun-form')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.parentElement.querySelector('input[name$="-DELETE"][type="checkbox"]').checked = true;
        e.target.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
});

function sunCheckOne() {
    const x = document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="sunday_bool"][type="checkbox"]');
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="sunday_bool"][type="checkbox"]')[i].checked =
            !document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="sunday_bool"][type="checkbox"]')[i].checked;
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#sun-not-available');

btn.addEventListener('click', updateBtn);

function updateBtn() {
    if (btn.value === 'Not Available Sunday') {
        btn.value = "I'm Available Sunday";
    } else {
        btn.value = 'Not Available Sunday';
    }
}

function sunHideShow() {
    const S = document.getElementById("sun-hide-id");
    if (S.style.display === "none") {
        S.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        S.style.display = "none";
    }
}


const sunHide = document.getElementById("sun-hide-id");
const sunTrueBool = document.getElementById('input[name="sunday_bool"][type="checkbox"]');
document.onload = function boolNotAvailable() {
    if (sunTrueBool === true) {
        sunHide.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        sunHide.style.display = "block";
    }
}




document.write("good"); 


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/availability_update_new.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" class="sun-not-available" value="Not Available Sunday" onclick="sunCheckOne(); sunHideShow()"
           id="sun-not-available">

    <form id="all-add-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="sun-hide" id="sun-hide-id">
            <div class="sunday-all" id="sunday-all-id">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <legend class="bottom mb-4">Profiles Info</legend>
                <div class="sun-bool">
                    {{ sun_bool.sunday_bool }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ sunday_formset.management_form }}
            {% for sun_form in sunday_formset %}
                {% for hidden in sun_form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="sun_time_slot_form">

                    {{ sun_form }}

                    <button class="delete-sun-form" type="button" id="delete-sun-btn" onclick=""> Delete This
                        Sunday
                        Timeslot
                    </button>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button id="add-sun-form" type="button" class="button">Add Other Sunday Times</button>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/add_timeslot.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You don't get whether the checkbox is checked. You just get the element. Thus sunTrueBool will always be true :)

Comment: You're doing God's work Wimanicesir! Missed that completely. Thank you!

Comment: Next time please post a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor and rendered HTML instead of server code

Comment: Also no need to test a boolean for true or false. Also get the element in the on load and use querySelector since you are not using the ID of it `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("sun-hide-id").hidden = 
document.querySelector('input[name="sunday_bool"]').checked; });`

Comment: That didn't work either or any combination of my original code and yours. Even removing the document.querySelector('input[name="sunday_bool"]').checked; from the code won't even hide the element onload.

Comment: ohh wait I'm a liar. Ignore me. That was weird. Yes, I will not use server code~

Comment: Feel free to delete the question